# Does the Adult Swim iOS app support Chromecast?

Tags: iphone, chromecast

I want to stream Rick and Morty to my Chromecast from the Adult Swim iOS app. However, unlike most media apps, the Adult Swim app doesn't seem to be detecting my Chromecast automatically.

**Is it possible to stream Adult Swim shows to a Chromecast from an iPhone?**

Note: I am aware that developers need to manually add Chromecast support to an app for it to be streamed. However, it seems like an odd omission when Adult Swim's sister app *Cartoon Network* was [recently updated](http://www.androidauthority.com/cartoon-network-chromecast-773994/) to add Chromecast support.

Answer (score -1):

iOS **developers have to manually add support for Chromecast** streaming (video/audio).

If you want to stream the content of this app to a Chromecast, please [let the developers know](http://www.adultswim.com/footer/contact/). Only they are able to add support for it.

Did this answer your question?

Comment: I am aware that Chromecast support needs to be  implemented by the developers. I was specifically asking whether the Adult Swim app had Chromecast support.